# Any GUI apps / Easy method for creating Wifi Hotspot in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, hot-spot

I am on Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. I want to create a hotspot in a simple way so that I can share my LAN (wired) connection with my Android phone. Tried several method, including manually creating wifi hotspot (edit connection etc.) , but still not successful. At most, my phone is able to authenticate, but getting stuck at "Fetching IP address....." stage.

Please suggest any GUI apps or any script, using which I can easily create the Wifi hotspot.

Comment: Your wifi hotspot needs to provide an IP adress to your phone, that is normally done with a DHCP server/daemon. Your ISP is most likely not providing more than one IP to you, so you have to set it up yourself. Many usual/common/consumer routers do have DHCP functionality together with NAT - which also is required as you intend to "share internet".

Answer (score 0):

Delete every last connection you made and install these packages:

- Network-manager-pptp-gnome
- Dnsmasq-base

and reboot once.

Then try to create another connection manually:

- Edit Connections >> Add a new connection >> select Wi-Fi
- Select Hotspot in mode
- Select device to be a access point
- Set password in Wi-Fi security
- Click Save